# How to allow user to save inputs for further review

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I have made a small calculating website and I would like the authenticated user to save his/her calculations.

Overview:
I have a main page with 8 input fields and several labels/graphs displaying results information. Whenever you change one of the inputs, the labels and graphs update thanks to hooks.

The goal: loading data
I made a "Save" button, which, when clicked :

- saves all the inputs to firebase (this works fine already)
- create a link in /myaccount/dashboard, which redirects you to the main page with your saved inputs (that I need help with)

I am having a hard time finding for resources online. However, while looking for responsive calculating websites, I came across this one : https://optionstrat.com
Even-thought I have no idea what they are calculating it does what I'm looking for, ie : you can "save a trade" and then go to you account where all the saved trades are displayed.

Does anyone know a good tutorial how to do so ?

Thanks you :)

*Edit*
This is my save function in my App.js:

```
function Savecalc(){
  const calcRef = db.ref("User_"+auth.currentUser.uid);
  const newCalc = calcRef.push();
  newCalc.set({inputs:{a,b,c},outputs:{x,y}});
/* Then attribute an URL to a saved calculation*/
}
```

Then, in my Dashboard.js, I would have:

```
const db=app.database();
export default function Dashboard() {
/* getting the user calculations */

return (
<div>
<!-- Mapping of the user's calculations -->
</div>
)
```

Comment: you can save your info to local storage,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are probably looking for is a little library called `react-router-dom`. This library essentially provides a collection of navigational components that you can employ to navigate around your app. Here is a basic [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic). Once you install it into your project, you should create a separate `AppRouter.js` file that might resemble something along the lines:

```
import React from 'react';
// Install the react-router-dom package
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// Further install the history package
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'; 
// Import your dashboard component and all other components you wish to create a route to
// This is just an example
import HomePage from '../components/Homepage';
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard';
// You will need to create a Page Not Found component that redirects when a wrong URL is inserted
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' component={HomePage} exact={true} />
      <Route path='/myaccount/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Then in your main/app.js file you will need to add the `AppRouter` component. It should look something like this:

```
const Application = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>  // if using react-redux, otherwise ignore Provider
      <AppRouter />   
  </Provider>
);

ReactDom.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You can also create public and private routes (e.g. accessible only for signed in users). Examples of these can be found [here](https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e).

Comment: Hello, yeah, no, I know how to make route, I'm looking for a way for a user to save data so that he/she can load them later on, like in the example I provided at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the user's calculations, you could then query them on whatever page you want to display them on e.g. /myaccount/dashboard.

You can then map over them and display them in the UI as links, where the link could be something like /myaccount/dashboard/YlxIJ2zOxI9KYJ5Dag6t where YlxIJ2zOxI9KYJ5Dag6t is the auto-generated document ID from Firestore.

Assuming you are using React Router, you can then have a route such as:

```
<Route exact path="/myaccount/dashboard/:id">
```

On this page, you can get the ID of the document from the parameters using React Router's useParams hook like so:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

You can then query the specific calculation's info in useEffect, and display them however you want.

Let me know if this is what you need, or if you need more help with any step!

Comment: Yep, this looks like it. I'm giving it a try and come back to you asap. Thanks ! :)

Comment: Hello, I gave it a try but couldnt figure it out by myself. I successfully got the calculations from a user but thats it. I have no idea how to map etc.. I edited my post so you can see :)

Comment: Could you post some code of the part you find difficult? It would make it easier for me to see what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: I edited, I have no idea how to do stuff in comments :)